# Inserting selected Checkbox value to the database

Tags: php

This part of the code is fine i do not see any problem there but still i can not insert it to the data base the following message appears.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check (quantity) VALUES ('2')' at line 1

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          $checkBox = $_POST['mycheck_box'];    
          for($i=0; $i< sizeof($checkBox); $i++){    
          echo $query = "INSERT INTO check (quantity) VALUES ('".$checkBox[$i]."')";
          echo "<br/>";
                        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
          }
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: you won't even have any value stored at $_POST['mychk'] if it wasn't checked

Comment: ok but i do select one value for the first example and the error message shows up what could possibly be the problem any ideas.

Comment: Don't use unfiltered values directly in queries. Escape, or use a simpler and more contemporary database interface (PDO with prepared statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `check` (quantity) VALUES ('".$checkBox[$i]."')";
```

CHECK is a MySQL keyword when creating tables.

On a side note, you should be filtering any $_POST values you receive from a form before doing anything with a database.

Comment: Mate You are THE MAN. Thanks a lot it worked i never New that you can escape table name. Could you please explain to me what you did does to the query.

Comment: @BashaMan Adding backticks (`) to a table name is usually a good idea to avoid running into keyword problems. All it does is tell MySQL to treat it as a name. Glad I could help

Comment: Thanks again and i have accepted and voted your answer keep up with the good help. thanks again